# Windows SSPI to Java GSSAPI interoperability to achieve SSO on EJB calls

Tags: java, windows, kerberos, gssapi, sspi

I have Java client running on Windows machine that calls remote EJB
on JBoss EAP/Wildfly running on Linux machine.
I use Kerberos to achieve SSO. Java client verifies the user against Windows domain
and pass his identity within EJB call to the JBoss server.

I started with JAAS and the builtin `com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule`.
It works correctly except one thing: user has to type his username and password
again. So, it is not a real SSO.

The problem is that Windows prohibits to export kerberos session key from its LSA credential cache.
It can be fixed by setting a specific Windows registry key on each client machine - but this is not acceptable for the customer.

Therefore I am trying to find an alternative solution.
I learned that Windows provides SSPI that shall be interoperable with GSSAPI used by Java. I use [**Waffle**](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) library to access SSPI from Java on the client. On the server I keep using JAAS, because it runs on Linux so I cannot use Waffle there.

I also learned that I don't need to implement LoginModule, rather I need SASL client.

So, I had a look how `com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client` works and I am trying to reimplement it using Waffle.

First step seems to work correctly - I obtain SSPI security context from Waffle, 
then get the initial token and send it to the server.
The server accepts the token and respond with its own token.

And now **the problem** comes. In the original SASL client the 'unwrap' operation is 
used to extract data from the server token, and 'wrap' operation is used to create
reply token to be sent to server.

**GSSAPI wrap / unwrap** operations shall correspond to **SSPI EncryptMessage / DecryptMessage** 
operations according to Microsoft doc. This two methods are not available in Waflle, but are available
in [NetAccountClient library](https://github.com/isuru-c-p/NetAccountClient/blob/master/src/main/java/nz/ac/auckland/netlogin/negotiation/win32/Secur32Ext.java).

However, I am not able to use them correctly. If I use a single SECBUFFER_STREAM then the DecryptMessage
is succesfull, however the data part of the token is not extracted and I don't know how to determine
the offset where it begins.

If I use SECBUFFER_STREAM and SECBUFFER_DATA as suggested by [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995352.aspx), then I get an error:
`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The message or signature supplied for verification has been altered`

I also tried other combinations of SECBUFFER types as suggested elsewhere, but without success.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

To source code of unwrap method:

```
    public byte[] unwrap(byte[] wrapper) throws LoginException {
        Sspi.SecBuffer.ByReference inBuffer = new Sspi.SecBuffer.ByReference(Secur32Ext.SECBUFFER_STREAM, wrapper);
        Sspi.SecBuffer.ByReference buffer = new Sspi.SecBuffer.ByReference();
        buffer.BufferType = Sspi.SECBUFFER_DATA;
        Secur32Ext.SecBufferDesc2 buffers = new Secur32Ext.SecBufferDesc2(inBuffer, buffer);

        NativeLongByReference pfQOP = new NativeLongByReference();

        int responseCode = Secur32Ext.INSTANCE.DecryptMessage(secCtx.getHandle(), buffers, new NativeLong(1), pfQOP);


        if (responseCode != W32Errors.SEC_E_OK) {
            throw handleError(responseCode);
        }

        byte[] data = buffer.getBytes();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Where did `SECBUFFER_VERSION` go?

Comment: Sorry for not showing it here, SECBUFFER_VERSION is added by default in Secur32Ext.SecBufferDesc2 constructor.

Comment: Any luck with this one?